# Mask out part first 12 characters of string with *?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

How can I take the value `123456789012345` or `1234567890123456` and turn it into:

`************2345` and `************3456`

The difference between the strings above is that one contains 15 digits and the other contains 16.

I have tried the following, but it does not keep the last 4 digits of the 15 digit number and now matter what the length of the string, be it 13, 14, 15, or 16, I want to mask all beginning digits with a *, but keep the last 4.  Here is what I have tried:

```
String.Format("{0}{1}", "************", str.Substring(11, str.Length - 12))
```

Comment: Are you wanting it to mask any number of digits but only show the last four?

Comment: @anjunatl - Yes, I want to mask all digits expect the last 4 regardless of length.

Comment: Can you post the context for that `String.Format` call? It works fine for me in a test app, so your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: It works, but when i used it on a 15 digit number it only showed the last 3 characters, I want to show all four now matter how long the string.

Comment: Added my function, the goal is flexibility.

Comment: Question, all the answers are nice, but is one more efficient than the other. Also, is my own answer in my question sufficient as well?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var str = "1234567890123456";
        if (str.Length > 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Concat(
                    "".PadLeft(12, '*'), 
                    str.Substring(str.Length - 4)
                )
            );
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you change from string.Format to string.Concat and in this scenario, it creates a 17 character length string, 13 *'s and the last 4 digits.

Comment: I just changed the 13 to 12 in the PadLeft function and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: `new String('*',12)` might be easier to read than `"".PadLeft(12,'*')`

Comment: @BobVale - Is there a performance or benefit to using either?

Comment: @Xaisoft depends as both could be cached in a variable. The `new  String('*',12)` method is easier to read and some code formatters (resharper) may start complaining and suggest you rewrite `""` as `String.Empty`

Comment: I think calling PadLeft on an empty string constant looks a little iffy.  Why not just str.Substring(str.Length - 4).PadLeft(16, '*')

Comment: what would be the code if i want to mask all the characters ? Please help me

Answer (score 46):

Something like this:

```
string s = "1234567890123"; // example
string result = s.Substring(s.Length - 4).PadLeft(s.Length, '*');
```

This will mask all but the last four characters of the string.  It assumes that the source string is at least 4 characters long.

Answer (score 16):

Easiest way: Create an extension method to extract the last four digits. Use that in your String.Format call.

For example:

```
public static string LastFour(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.length < 4)
    {
        return "0000";
    }
    return value.Substring(value.Length - 4, 4) 
}
```

In your code:

```
String.Format("{0}{1}", "************", str.LastFour());
```

In my opinion, this leads to more readable code, and it's reusable.

**EDIT:** Perhaps not the easiest way, but an alternative way that may produce more maintainable results. <shrug/>

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? He's clearly dealing with credit card numbers. Reusability is an issue.

Comment: I like the extension method, but only need it in one place, so a one liner would be nicer. Upvote

Comment: In my experience, you only *think* you need it in one place. :-)

Comment: Not my downvote, but If you go for a reusable solution, why not handle the case of a 1 to 3 characters input more gracefully, and make the number of characters a parameter, while you're at it?

Comment: @kuroineko At the time, this was for a specific case (masking SSNs). You could, of course, create an overload that takes additional arguments and makes it more usable. This was almost ten years ago, and I'd more than likely do that today. But in general, we don't create functionality until we actually need it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var maskSize = ccDigits.Length - 4;
var mask = new string('*', maskSize) + ccDigits.Substring(maskSize);
```

Comment: This works, but creates strings that are all 17 characters long.

Comment: Really? I seem to get 15 or 16, depending.

Comment: Against this 13 length value `22222222222221`, it returns 17 characters.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ:

```
char maskBy = '*'; 
string input = "123456789012345";
int count = input.Length <= 4 ? 0 : input.Length - 4; 
string output = new string(input.Select((c, i) => i < count ? maskBy : c).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
static private String MaskInput(String input, int charactersToShowAtEnd)
{
  if (input.Length < charactersToShowAtEnd)
  {
    charactersToShowAtEnd = input.Length;
  }
  String endCharacters = input.Substring(input.Length - charactersToShowAtEnd);
  return String.Format(
    "{0}{1}", 
    "".PadLeft(input.Length - charactersToShowAtEnd, '*'), 
    endCharacters
    );
}
```

Adjust the function header as required, call with:

```
MaskInput("yourInputHere", 4);
```

Comment: i like it, but i have replaced charactersToShowAtEnd = input.Length; by return input ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
private string MaskDigits(string input)
{
    //take first 6 characters
    string firstPart = input.Substring(0, 6);

    //take last 4 characters
    int len = input.Length;
    string lastPart = input.Substring(len - 4, 4);

    //take the middle part (****)
    int middlePartLenght = len - (firstPart.Length + lastPart.Length);
    string middlePart = new String('*', middlePartLenght);

    return firstPart + middlePart + lastPart;
}

MaskDigits("1234567890123456");

// output : "123456******3456"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
    private string MaskString(string s)
    {
        int NUM_ASTERISKS = 4;

        if (s.Length < NUM_ASTERISKS) return s;

        int asterisks = s.Length - NUM_ASTERISKS;
        string result = new string('*', asterisks);
        result += s.Substring(s.Length - NUM_ASTERISKS);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This was what I was going for but this is more elegant I think. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Regex with a match evaluator will do the job

```
string filterCC(string source) {
  var x=new Regex(@"^\d+(?=\d{4}$)");
  return x.Replace(source,match => new String('*',match.Value.Length));
}
```

This will match any number of digits followed by 4 digits and the end (it won't include the 4 digits in the replace). The replace function will replace the match with a string of * of equal length.

This has the additional benefit that you could use it as a validation algorthim too.  Change the first + to {11,12} to make it match a total of 15 or 16 chars and then you can use `x.IsMatch` to determine validity.

EDIT

Alternatively if you always want a 16 char result just use

```
 return x.Replace(source,new String('*',12));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// "123456789".MaskFront results in "****56789"
public static string MaskFront(this string str, int len, char c)
    {
        var strArray = str.ToCharArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if(i < strArray.Length)
            {
                strArray[i] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return string.Join("", strArray);
    }

// "123456789".MaskBack results in "12345****"
public static string MaskBack(this string str, int len, char c)
{
    var strArray = str.ToCharArray();

    var tracker = strArray.Length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (tracker > -1)
        {
            strArray[tracker] = c;
            tracker--;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return string.Join("", strArray);
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
static string Mask(string str)
{
    if (str.Length <= 4) return str;
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(.*?)(\d{4})$");
    string result = String.Empty;
    if (rgx.IsMatch(str))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rgx.Matches(str)[0].Groups[1].Length; i++)
            result += "*";
        result += rgx.Matches(str)[0].Groups[2];
        return result;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mask from start and from end with sending char

```
public static string Maskwith(this string value, int fromStart, int fromEnd, char ch)
    {
        return (value?.Length >= fromStart + fromEnd) ?
             string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(ch, fromStart)) + value.Substring(fromStart, value.Length - (fromStart + fromEnd)) + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(ch, fromEnd))
             : "";
    } //Console.WriteLine("mytestmask".Maskwith(2,3,'*')); **testm***
```

show chars from start and from end by passing value and mask the middle

```
 public static string MasktheMiddle(this string value, int visibleCharLength, char ch)
    {
        if (value?.Length <=  (visibleCharLength * 2))
            return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(ch,value.Length));
        else
            return value.Substring(0, visibleCharLength) + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(ch, value.Length - (visibleCharLength * 2))) + value.Substring(value.Length - visibleCharLength);

    } //Console.WriteLine("mytestmask".MasktheMiddle(2,'*')); Result: my******sk
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I take the value 123456789012345 or 1234567890123456 and turn it into:
>
> ************2345 and ************3456

one more way to do this:

`var result =  new string('*',0,value.Length - 4) + new string(value.Skip(value.Length - 4).ToArray())`

// or using string.Join

Answer (score 0):

An extension method using C# 8's index and range:

```
public static string MaskStart(this string input, int showNumChars, char maskChar = '*') =>
    input[^Math.Min(input.Length, showNumChars)..]
        .PadLeft(input.Length, maskChar);
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way

```
   string s = "1234567890123"; // example
   int l = s.Length;
   s = s.Substring(l - 4);
   string r = new string('*', l);
   r = r + s;
```