# custom string format puzzler

Tags: c#, string, format

We have a requirement to display bank routing/account data that is masked with asterisks, except for the last 4 numbers.  It seemed simple enough until I found this in unit testing:

```
string.Format("{0:****1234}",61101234)
```

```
is properly displayed as: "****1234"
```

but

```
string.Format("{0:****0052}",16000052)
```

```
is incorrectly displayed (due to the zeros??): "****1600005252""
```

If you use the following in C# it works correctly, but I am unable to use this because DevExpress automatically wraps it with "{0: ... }" when you set the displayformat without the curly brackets:

```
string.Format("****0052",16000052)
```

Can anyone think of a way to get this format to work properly inside curly brackets (with the full 8 digit number passed in)?

UPDATE:  The string.format above is only a way of testing the problem I am trying to solve.  It is not the finished code.  I have to pass to DevExpress a string format inside braces in order for the routing number to be formatted correctly.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
string.Format("{0:****0000}", 16000052);
```

But I have not seen that with the * inline like that. Without knowing better I probably would have done:

```
string.Format("{0}{1}", "****", str.Substring(str.Length-4, 4);
```

Or even dropping the format call if I *knew* the length.

These approaches are worthwhile to look through: [Mask out part first 12 characters of string with *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035192/mask-out-part-first-12-characters-of-string-with)

As you are alluding to in the comments, this should also work:

```
string.Format("{0:****####}", 16000052);
```

The difference is using the 0's will display a zero if no digit is present, # will not. Should be moot in your situation.

If for some reason you want to print the literal zeros, use this:

```
string.Format("{0:****\0\052}", 16000052);
```

But note that this is not doing anything with your input at all.

Comment: That is a valid approach as it also returns ****0052, but again, DevExpress will wrap that and set it using {0:****0052}.  This has to be passed in with the format entirely inside curly braces or it wont work correctly.

Comment: I am unsure of exactly what you mean in the comment, but the issue I think is those 4 numbers should always be zeros, as the placeholder for a number. If you want to include the numbers in the format so they are treated as plan text I think you would have to escape them somehow (like '\0' ?)

Comment: Specifically in your fist case you are not formatting the input at all, just printing out the string following the 0:

Comment: Ideally, if the zeros in 0052 could be replaced with ##52, or could somehow be escaped inside the format specifier that would solve the problem.  For some reason, C# wants to replace each 0 with a chunk of the number.  I'll see if there is someway to get DevExpress to see the value as alphanumeric.  Thanks!

Comment: Re-reading you question and comment, I am uncertian why the first solution of `string.Format("{0:****0000}", 16000052);` does not work when passing it as you describe?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  The all zeros and the escaped sequence dont work - which does not make sense at all.  One of the reasons I rarely post here is 1) 99% of the answers are already here, 2) there is usually nothing I can't find a good workaround for or 3) when there isn't an answer here, I am doing something that nobody else has ever tried, which means I am probably choosing a lousy solution - which is what I think I'm doing here.   Why in the world Microsoft is still using a 20+ year old method for formatting strings is completely beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame that you haven't included the code which is *building* the format string. It's very odd to have the format string depend on the data in the way that it looks like you have.

I would *not* try to do this in a format string; instead, I'd write a method to convert the credit card number into an "obscured" string form, quite possibly just using `Substring` and string concatenation. For example:

```
public static string ObscureFirstFourCharacters(string input)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    return "****" + input.Substring(4);
}
```

(It's not clear what the data type of your credit card number is. If it's a numeric type and you need to convert it to a string first, you need to be careful to end up with a fixed-size string, left-padded with zeroes.)

Comment: The routing number is an example.  The code is: routingNumber.DisplayFormatString = routingNumber.Substring(routingNumber.Length - 4, 4).PadLeft(routingNumber.Length, '*')    It formats correctly without the curly brackets, but I have to use the braces or DevExpress will use the wrong format.

Comment: @AaronCarta: It's *really* unclear what DevExpress has to do with any of this. You should clarify your question to explain your situation more clearly.